# Nunit results

Tags: vb.net, nunit, watin

I am using Nunit results for managerial view of all the tests. After reading nunit doc it says it automatically update the results xml file after running the tests. But In my case it keep showing me the old results in index file where as updated reults in actual file. Any idea how can I update the index file according to the latest results.

Answer (score 2):

According to NUnit-Console 2.4.8 [command line docs](http://nunit.com/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.4.8) the xml output is written by default to TestResult.xml in the working directory. You can use the /xml command line option to specify a different file name. For example:

```
nunit-console /xml:console-test.xml nunit.tests.dll
```

My guess is that either you are specifying a filename with the /xml flag but looking in vain for updated results in TestResult.xml or you are *not* using the /xml flag and looking in vain for updated results in a file with some other name. Probably the former.